# Prevent Linux Probing for Partitions

Tags: linux, partition, udev, removable-storage

How to avoid any type of partition probes when a HDD is detected by a booted up system, in a way that it only detects basic drive features as model, sector size and capacity, consequently creating just one device file as `/dev/sda`? Is it a libata/kernel issue?

It's about a data recovery experience with a damaged HDD that sectors corresponding to partition table should not being read. I'm not talking about auto-mount, it's already disabled.

The sectors linked to partitions are on a scratched area. When heads pass over there, drive crashes.

This is what happens when a healthy HDD is attached:

**Dmesg Output**

```
Oct 13 16:21:42 wks-01 kernel: [ 906.796660] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)...
Oct 13 16:21:42 wks-01 kernel: [ 906.915646] sdb: sdb1
```

(I need to disable that last routine)

**Udev Output**

```
KERNEL[906.915935] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb8/8-3/8-3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)<br>
KERNEL[906.915999] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb8/8-3/8-3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sdb/**sdb1** (block)  (**I need to disable this routine)** ... <br>
UDEV [907.392087] add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb8/8-3/8-3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to read the partition table?  The kernel will not write anything to the disk until you issue some command from userspace.

Comment: Because those sectors shouldn't even be read. They're on a scratched area. When heads pass over there, drive crashes.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hm... interesting, to not read the drive you would need to disable the right kernel modules.  My take on it would be to `rmmod sd_mod scsi_mod`.  But you can't do it if your system is booted from a scsi disk (e.g. a USB stick or CD drive, or an actual disk), which isn't really feasible (maybe a network boot?).  A better approach may be to let the disk crash an then power it back with hdparm.  What happens when it crashes?

Comment: I need to disable probing for partitions, not hdd detection. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're on the right path with udev, i forgot udev.  On the kernel side `libata` and `ata_generic` should deal with the disk and the `scsi` stuff with the partitions, but I'm not that confident in that.  Nevertheless I've edited your question to look a little better and tagged with `udev` since we want to attract people that are good with udev config.

Comment: I guess kernel recognizes partitions first, so after that udev creates /dev/* files. The question is: Which one is responsible for this job (libata, or scsi_mod or whatever)?

Comment: ... I mean partition table is read by kernel and HDD heads runs over the damaged area. I don't think udev can stop that kernel routine.

What do you think?

Comment: I've tried, oh I tried, screwed my system 2 times making udev rules.  And could not force the kernel to not send me a n uevent for `sdb1`.  `scsi_mod` is responsible for all lock devices (pretty much all), `libata` translates SCSI commands into SATA comands so it is a layer below.  An external (USB) drive will use SCSI but not libata, since the translation is SCSI->USB then.  I added a big piece reasoning below.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: I've posted a quicker/safer method [below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691138/240014) using a kernel module**

As @grochmal notes, there's no built in way to do this, although if you are willing to compile your own kernel, it's pretty straight forward:

In the file `block/partition-generic.c` add the following code before the function `rescan_partitions`:

```
int do_partscan = 1;

static const struct kernel_param_ops do_partscan_param_ops = {
    .set    = param_set_int,
    .get    = param_get_int,
};

module_param_cb(do_partscan, &do_partscan_param_ops, &do_partscan, 0644);
```

and insert this code at the beginning of that function:

```
if (!do_partscan) {
    bdev->bd_invalidated = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

this will provide you with a module parameter (in `/sys/module/...` that you can use to toggle partition scanning. If it is set to `0` any scan will return immediately with no partitions. If you need to, you can flip it back to `1` and run `blockdev --rereadpt <device>` to load partitions on an attached disk.

[I'm not sure where the param will be in the `/sys/module` tree - look for it with `find /sys/module -name do_partscan`. I think you can set

```
#undef MODULE_PARAM_PREFIX
#define MODULE_PARAM_PREFIX "block."
```

before the code `module_param_cb ...` to put it into `/sys/module/block/parameters/do_partscan` but I haven't tested it like that.]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way.

From the UDEV perspective the partition uevents are sent directly from the kernel, there is no indirection.

From the kernel side things happen from [`__blkdev_get()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/block_dev.c#L1241) which will always read at least some of the partition table with [`disk_get_part()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c#L62).  That will read enough of the partition table to understand what kind of partition table it is.

As far as you can go is to unset `CONFIG_MSDOS_PARTITION` during kernel compilation so that [`msdos_partition()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/partitions/msdos.c#L447) it will not be used inside [`check_partition()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/partitions/check.c#L142).  I'm not sure how much of the partition it reads more compared to `disk_get_part()` though.

#### Notes

- This is assuming that your disk uses an MSDOS partition.  There are several other `CONFIG_*_PARTIOTION` parameters in [`/block/partitions/check.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/partitions/check.c).
- You would need to boot this kernel from a drive that uses a different partition type than the one you want to backup.  This may or may not be troublesome (GPT partitions are quite viable today).
- Another way is that, maybe, you could `rmmod scsi`.  But that would require you to not need the SCSI subsystem for anything.  The only way I can think you can achieve that is through a network boot.  You could then connect the damaged disk, use `modprobe scsi` to get the subsystem back, and make the node (`mknod`) by hand.  This is hypothetical (I have not tried this), I'm not sure if `mknod` will not trigger `__blkdev_get()` screwing all the effort.

Comment: Do you have any comments on my new answers?

Answer (score 1):

From Linux kernel 4 and on, you can use a `livepatch` module to block reading the partition table. This is much faster and easier than recompiling the entire kernel. I've created a module that covers the various forms of the `livepatch` api using `IF` macros.

This has been tested on `5.13.0-28` under `Ubuntu Server 20.10`. I have not tried on other kernels - the code may be incorrect.

Here is `no_partscan.c`:

```
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/livepatch.h>

#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/genhd.h>

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(5,4,179)

static int livepatch_rescan_partitions(struct gendisk *disk, struct block_device *bdev)
{
    pr_warn("Intercepted partition read for disk: %s.\n", disk->disk_name);
    return -EIO;
}

static struct klp_func funcs[] = {
    {
        .old_name = "rescan_partitions",
        .new_func = livepatch_rescan_partitions,
    }, { }
};

#else

static int livepatch_blk_add_partitions(struct gendisk *disk)
{
    pr_warn("Intercepted partition read for disk: %s.\n", disk->disk_name);
    return 0;
}

#endif

static struct klp_func funcs[] = {
    {
        .old_name = "blk_add_partitions",
        .new_func = livepatch_blk_add_partitions,
    }, { }
};

static struct klp_object objs[] = {
    {
        /* name being NULL means vmlinux */
        .funcs = funcs,
    }, { }
};

static struct klp_patch patch = {
    .mod = THIS_MODULE,
    .objs = objs,
};

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(5,0,21)

static int livepatch_init(void)
{
    int ret;

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(4,15,18) && LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4,11,12)
    if (!klp_have_reliable_stack() && !patch.immediate) {
         // Use of this option will also prevent removal of the patch.
         // See Documentation/livepatch/livepatch.txt for more details.
        patch.immediate = true;
        pr_notice("The consistency model isn't supported for your architecture.  Bypassing safety mechanisms and applying the patch immediately.\n");
    }
#endif

    ret = klp_register_patch(&patch);
    if (ret)
        return ret;
    ret = klp_enable_patch(&patch);
    if (ret) {
        WARN_ON(klp_unregister_patch(&patch));
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void livepatch_exit(void)
{
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(4,11,12)
    WARN_ON(klp_disable_patch(&patch)); 
#endif
    WARN_ON(klp_unregister_patch(&patch));
}

#else

static int livepatch_init(void)
{
    return klp_enable_patch(&patch);
}

static void livepatch_exit(void)
{
}

#endif

module_init(livepatch_init);
module_exit(livepatch_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_INFO(livepatch, "Y");
```

It can be used with the following `Makefile`:

```
obj-m := no_partscan.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

(Please note that if you see a "missing separator" running that Makefile, replace the four spaces with a tab.)

Afterwards, when you are ready to block the partition reads, use:

`sudo insmod no_partscan`

To disable the patch, use:

`echo 0 > /sys/kernel/livepatch/no_partscan/enabled`

This will remove the patch but it is still installed as a module; you will have to run `sudo rmmod no_partscan.ko` and then `insmod` etc. again to reenable it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found works from kernel `2.6` and up; It works by using `kretprobe` to intercept the `add_disk` function and setting a flag that blocks partition reads. When the function returns, the flag is restored to its original state. This way, you can manually read the partitions later (using `partprobe` etc.).

This method also allows disabling\reenabling the block on the fly, by setting the state in `/sys/module/no_partscan/parameters/enabled` to `0` or `1`.

I have tested it on `AMD64` but not on `x86` or `ARM`. The code relies on picking the registers that correspond to the function arguments; that is defined per-architecture and may be incorrect.

Here is the code for the module:

```
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/genhd.h>

#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
#define ARG1 ax
#define ARG2 bx
#elif defined CONFIG_X86_64
#define ARG1 di
#define ARG2 si
#elif defined CONFIG_ARM || CONFIG_ARM64
#define ARG1 regs[0]
#define ARG2 regs[1]
#endif

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(4,7,10)
#define ARG ARG1
static char func_name[NAME_MAX] = "add_disk";
#else // after 4.7.10, add_disk is a macro pointing to device_add_disk, which has the disk as its 2nd argument
#define ARG ARG2
static char func_name[NAME_MAX] = "device_add_disk";
#endif

static int enabled = 1;
module_param(enabled, int, 0664);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(enabled, "Enable intercepting disk initializing so we can block partscan.");

struct instance_data {
    struct gendisk *disk;
};

static int entry_handler(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    struct instance_data *data;
    struct gendisk *disk;

    data = (struct instance_data *)ri->data;
    disk = (struct gendisk *)(regs->ARG);

    if (!enabled || disk->flags & GENHD_FL_NO_PART_SCAN) {
        data->disk = NULL;
    } else {
        pr_warn("Intercepted partition read for disk: %s.\n", disk->disk_name);
        disk->flags |= (GENHD_FL_NO_PART_SCAN);
        data->disk = disk; // store this so we can remove the NO_PARTSCAN flag on function return
    }
    return 0;
}

static int ret_handler(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    struct instance_data *data;

    data = (struct instance_data *)ri->data;
    if (data->disk)
        data->disk->flags &= ~(GENHD_FL_NO_PART_SCAN);

    return 0;
}

static struct kretprobe my_kretprobe = {
    .handler        = ret_handler,
    .entry_handler  = entry_handler,
    .data_size      = sizeof(struct instance_data),
    .maxactive      = 20,
};

static int __init kretprobe_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    my_kretprobe.kp.symbol_name = func_name;
    ret = register_kretprobe(&my_kretprobe);
    if (ret < 0) {
        pr_warn("register_kretprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit kretprobe_exit(void)
{
    unregister_kretprobe(&my_kretprobe);
    pr_info("kretprobe at unregistered\n");

    /* nmissed > 0 suggests that maxactive was set too low. */
    if (my_kretprobe.nmissed) pr_warn("Missed probing %d instances.\n", my_kretprobe.nmissed);
}

module_init(kretprobe_init)
module_exit(kretprobe_exit)
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

It can be built and inserted just like the `livepatch` module in the other answer.

Comment: Can confirm this works on 4.19